# Возможно ли создание голосового помощника с помощью electron js?

Tags: javascript, electron

```js
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const{brandnetwork, BrowserWindow, app} = require('electron')
// Открытие программы
let win;

function createWindow(){
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 830,
        height: 630,
        icon:__dirname + "/img/lamp.png"
        });
        // Изеначальное открытие файоа
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));
    // Среда разработки
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
// Обработка закрытия
    win.on('closed', () =>{
        win = null;
    });
}
// Запуск программы
app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', ()=> {
    app.quit();
})
```

```html
  <button onclick="speech()">Слушать</button>
  <button onclick="talk()">Проговорить</button>
  <button onclick="stop()">Остановить</button>

  <script>
      var recognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

recognizer.interimResults = true;

// Какой язык будем распознавать
recognizer.lang = 'ru-Ru';

// Используем колбек для обработки результатов
recognizer.onresult = function (event) {
  var result = event.results[event.resultIndex];
  if (result.isFinal) {
    alert('Вы сказали: ' + result[0].transcript);
  } else {
    console.log('Промежуточный результат: ', result[0].transcript);
  }
};

function speech () {
  // Начинаем слушать микрофон и распознавать голос;
  systemPrefences.getMediaAccessStatus(meddiaType);
  recognizer.start();
}
  </script>
```

Возможно ли создание голосового помощника с помощью electron js?
Пытаюсь это сделать, использовал SpeechRecognition, но он его не видит, и доступ к микрофону не даёт, вообще возможно ли это сделать при помощи electron?

Comment: da.............

Comment: С помощью чего этот можно сделать?

Comment: Проговаривание можно сделать без библиотек с помощью window.speechSynthesis: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/speak